# How to quote identifiers with LINQPad + IQ Driver + MySQL?

Tags: mysql, linqpad

I'm working with a rather horrible schema designed by an external party and it contains a table named `order` so when I invoke a query that references this table in LINQPad I get a SQL syntax error.

I know how to quote the identifier in MySQL, but I can't see how to do this with LINQPad and the IQ Driver.  Looking at [this](http://www.mindscapehq.com/forums/thread/4249) it seems to be up to the driver implementation.

Comment: Having the same problem with a table named `keys`.

Comment: Similar problem, but with column names: 'fulltext'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the backtick (`) to quote the tablename?

```
select * from `order`
```

If that doesn't work you may have to configure quoteIdentifiers [as described here](http://www.mindscapehq.com/Help/LightSpeed/html/P_Mindscape_LightSpeed_LightSpeedContext_QuoteIdentifiers.htm).